# intercept file download using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, excel

I have an api that produces a custom excel file based on the parameters of a request:

Here is the call for the excel file:

```
window.location = Service.API_ENDPOINT + '/report/GetAReport' + generateQueryParams();
```

The issue is that sometimes there is no data with which to populate the spreadsheet (that corresponds to the query params) and the user downloads an empty spreadsheet. In these cases I would like to pop up a message that says something to the effect of "no results for your parameters". The question is how to do this.

I was thinking that I could adjust the api to return something other than a file if there are no query results (perhaps even a server error) but then how do I act on it on the client side? I mean, how could I modify this call so that it downloads a file in the cases that there is one but displays a message when something else is sent by the server and what should the "something else" be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could setup the server to respond to a HEAD request at that path that returns a 404 if it would result in an empty spreadsheet, then make an ajax request to ensure it isn't 404 before redirecting the user to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @KevinB hmm the request is fairly time consuming though. Any way to do this without having to crunch through the same server side logic twice?

Comment: Not really, unless you want to download it clientside, somehow inspect it, then attempt to force the browser to download it using a download attribute and a data-uri (which doesn't work in all browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a HEAD request against the same endpoint and return a different status code if the spreadsheet is empty.

Then, before you do the window.location change, perform an AJAX request with the HEAD method. If the status is 200, proceed with downloading. If it's 302 (for example), show an alert.

Comment: hmm the request is fairly time consuming though. Any way to do this without having to crunch through the same server side logic twice?

Comment: You don't need to do 2 requests then, perhaps try this:

Determine the size in bytes of the empty spreadsheet. I assume that an empty spreadsheet would always be the same size? Then, instead of doing window.location to point to the file, do an ajax request for the file.

If the response size matches the empty file size, then show the error.

Comment: How do I store the file and how do I send it for download once I have determined that it has data?

Comment: The file would get held in memory, the browser handles that. You've already downloaded it by performing the AJAX request.

When the API call returns, check the Content-Length attribute on the response. If the length matches the empty file length, show an error. If not, the response data will be the file you want the user to download. You would have to figure out some way to use that data blob though.